# Grails background process

Tags: grails, scheduled-tasks

I am fairly new to Grails and I have a requirement that I don't know how to implement.
I need to make a process that will be running along the side with Grails application and making remote calls, process received data and writing it to DB so that Grails application can make use of it.

So far I figured that I need to leverage domain controllers, but I am not sure how to make a separate process that is constantly running in the background and updating DB.

Is it possible? Can I get references or code examples. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is Quartz via the http://grails.org/plugin/quartz or http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2 plugins. I've used the quartz plugin and the Job classes you create are artifacts (like controllers, services, etc.) so they support dependency injection. Services are the best place to do transactional database work, so inject one or more services into your Job classes to handle database work.

The quartz2 plugin is newer so you may have more luck using it in current versions of Grails, but it might not have all of the features of the older plugin.

Comment: dang it Burt beat me by a minute!

Comment: We've used Quartz extensively in our Grails 1.3.7 apps, and it's worked flawlessly for us. Highly recommend it. One thing we add to every job is to check a config value to see if the job should run or not. That allows us to turn the job off in dev and staging modes if we need to.

Comment: The OP was a bit vague on if this is a cron-like set of tasks or if this was a job-like set of tasks. Quartz is great for scheduled stuff, but a processing queue is much better for job-like tasks. Is there any light-weight, job queue that is similar to quartz but for the other use-case? (ie. something lighter weight than setting up a queue server like RabbitMQ)

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? I am just a beginner, it is hard to figure out how to write a service & such. I installed quartz, but the rest of docs bring a bit of confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Found nice tutorial that helped me get started fairly quickly:
[link](http://blog.lucastex.com/2009/04/02/3of25-building-a-rss-reader-with-quartz-plugin-a-simple-grails-tutorial/)