# Grails Quartz & threads inside service

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I have a question about Quartz and running threads inside Service class.

I got my previous question answered: [Grails background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135599/grails-background-process), however I have another issue.

**Setup:** I have a Job that is setup to run a Service and it works perfectly. However inside a Service class I have an algorithm that can run in parallel.

**Issue:** Typically I would setup code to run in parallel in the following very simple way:

```
Item.each {
   Thread.start {
      do some calculations here    
      write to DB
   }
}
```

However, since my code need to write into DB and I need to leverage domain classes and at that point my code brakes. Hibernate complains that threads don't have access to something.

I am not sure why I can't use threads inside Service class and leverage domain class. Can someone help me with this dilemma? 
Do I need to create threads in a special way? May be I shouldn't be creating threads in Service class (since Service class seem to be running inside threads )? Do I need to move my code into Job class?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try having a look at the executor plugin and wrap the call to the service with: runAsync { service.serviceMethod() }

Comment: Further to what @Steve says, by default, new threads *will not* have a hibernate session attached (which is needed to use hibernate) - hence the errors you're seeing.  The executor plugin manages attaching hibernate session for you (so does, in fact, the quartz plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Threads won't have a Hibernate Session bound to them by default.  To attach a Hibernate Session, try the following:

```
Item.each {
    Thread.start {
        Item.withTransaction {
            do some calculations here    
            write to DB
        }
    }
}
```

You could also look into [GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) for an easy to use parallelization framework.